# Angular 4 : HTML links generated from data received from database dont appear until page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

First off, thanks to everyone at SO. If I have been able to learn and build something of use in 2 months it was because of you all. I am actually surprised I have been able to pull this off.

---

There is an issue with the html template. I am getting the navigation links from the firebase realtime database based on the user permission. The way it happens is:

a) User comes to the login page. Navigation bar is on top but since the **LoggedIn** flag is set to false, shows no links.

b) User logs in and goes to his dashboard.

c) Navigation bar still has no values even thought **LoggedIn** is now true.

d) **ONLY AFTER** page refresh does the navigation bar show all the links.

The relevant html where I think the problems arises. I am using both *ngIf and *ngFor. The span used to be an ng-template earlier.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" *ngIf="loggedIn">
    <!--This part is pushed to the left-->

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <span *ngFor="let mainPerm of keyValues">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [id]="mainPerm" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{mainPerm.toUpperCase()}}
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" [attr.aria-labelledby]="mainPerm">
            <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="dropDownList[mainPerm]['View']"
               [routerLink]="dropDownList[mainPerm]['View']">View Details (<fa name="search" class="ml-auto"></fa>)</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="dropDownList[mainPerm]['Add']"
               [routerLink]="dropDownList[mainPerm]['Add']">Add New  (<fa name="plus"></fa>)</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </span>
    </ul>
```

The complete html template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">

  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">
    <img src="../../assets/LOGO-WHITE.png" height="30">
  </a>
  <!--Only if the users are logged in-->


  <!--navbar close button-->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <!--navigation which is linked to close button-->

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" *ngIf="loggedIn">
    <!--This part is pushed to the left-->

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <span *ngFor="let mainPerm of keyValues">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [id]="mainPerm" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{mainPerm.toUpperCase()}}
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" [attr.aria-labelledby]="mainPerm">
            <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="dropDownList[mainPerm]['View']"
               [routerLink]="dropDownList[mainPerm]['View']">View Details (<fa name="search" class="ml-auto"></fa>)</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="dropDownList[mainPerm]['Add']"
               [routerLink]="dropDownList[mainPerm]['Add']">Add New  (<fa name="plus"></fa>)</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </span>
    </ul>

    <!--This pushes the right side to the right-->

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="totalValues.name">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="settings" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span [class]="network">{{totalValues?.name}} <fa name="cog"></fa></span>
        </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="settings">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/">Edit Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/">Change Password</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Log Out</a>
          </div>

      </li>

    </ul>

    <!-- All navigation links come until here-->
  </div>



</nav>
```

The relevant typescript file:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private navbar: NewNavbarService, private user: NewUsersService) {
    this.userDetails = this.user.appUser$.subscribe(value => {
      this.totalValues = value;
      this.changeNavDetails(this.totalValues.permission);
      this.loggedIn = true;  <--- Tried to use *ngIF to control it in the html
    });
```

Comment: Figured it out. I keep forgetting the simple fact that we have to check for undefined  / null values.

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip:
You can use question mark on the variable, so it will refer only to defined object.
For example:

```
<div>{{user?.name}}</div>
```